# How to align a dynamic height footer to the bottom of a page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my current project i have footer with dynamic contents ie all links are from database, can add any number of links.Now i want to position it on the bottom of my page.I have searched a lot to get a solution but all are coming with a fixed height footer.Is there any solution for this? This project is done with bootstrap 3.

Comment: What do you mean by fixed height footer? If you want the height to adjust automatically, use height:auto. can you provide a fiddle of what you have tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sobha_wds/agukj/

Comment: I guess your footer is at the bottom of the page only, if I am understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: Yes...It should align to the very bottom of my page.Irrespective of the content in the middle section.

Comment: use - position: absolute; bottom:3px; in your style for footer element, use your preferred value other than 3px for bottom.